# Network Community Detection and Modularity using Node Attributes

Tags: r, attributes, nodes, igraph, network-analysis

I have a large political network with the nodes representing people and the ties representing a rhetorical similarity score between each pair of nodes. I know how to run a general community detection using the network ties and create node attributes containing the membership of each node, like this:

```
cwt <- cluster_walktrap(g, weights = E(g)$weight, steps = 4, merges = TRUE, modularity = TRUE, membership = TRUE)
modularity(cwt)
V(g)$cwt <- membership(cwt) 

cle <- cluster_leading_eigen(g, weights = NULL)
modularity(cle)
V(g)$cle <- membership(cle) 

clv <- cluster_louvain (g, weights = E(g)$weight)
modularity(clv)
V(g)$clv <- membership(clv) node.
```

But I want to see how well partisans cluster together. In the words, I want to test the modularity using a node attribute. I have an attribute for each node (`V(g)#partisanship`) that specifies "republican" or "democrat". I want to find out the modularity score for all the nodes with "democrat", as well as for "republican".

How can I test modularity of a network using a specified node attribute (`V(g)#partisanship`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the modularity of a partitioning that you created yourself (instead of obtaining it with a community detection function), you simply need to represent that partitioning in igraph's standard format, i.e. a "membership vector".

Construct a vector `m` so that `m[i]` is `1` if node `i` is republican and `2` if node `i` is democrat. Then pass this to the `modularity` function.

A simple way to do this is

```r
modularity(g, factor(V(g)$partisanship))
```